# Adding images to Android Studio Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently working on various layouts that require a huge number of pictures. I have on the side pngs of letters and numbers. When I try to get an image view of a number png Android studio is unable to find that png. Is there a limit to the amount of pictures the drawable folder can store. Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okZwO.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name of the drawable resource can't start with number.